# Is robots.txt crawl-delay also for sub-pages?

Tags: python, web-crawler, robots.txt

I wrote a crawler for a certain webpage. This webpage has a robots.txt which looks like this:

```
User-Agent: * 
Crawl-delay: 30
```

So it's only allowed to crawl the site every 30 seconds (right?). But what about sub-pages? E.g. can I crawl the following sites without a delay of 30 seconds because they are different sub-pages:

```
www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/category_1 
www.mysite.com/category_2
```

Do I need to make a break of 30 seconds between these requests?

Thank you,
   Thomas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crawl delay tells the robot about the number of seconds to wait between successive requests to the same server.

Comment: So it's definitely about the same server, not the same page? Which means I need to make a break :(

Comment: @ThomasUhrig: Yes, it's definitely about the server. You definitely need to wait between requests.